# Docbook and strikethrough functionality

Tags: docbook

How to add to Docbook strikethrough functionality? I mean something like this <s>this is striked example text</s>. I mean HTML output generation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you are using [DocBook-XSL](https://sourceforge.net/projects/docbook/), here is how you can add the strike-through effect to inline content:

1. Set the `emphasis.propagates.style` parameter to 1.
2. Set the `html.stylesheet` parameter to a suitable value, for example `mystyle.css`.
3. Add the following to `mystyle.css`:

   ```
   span.strike { text-decoration: line-through; }
   ```
4. Use `<emphasis role="strike">some text</emphasis>` to  mark up text snippets in your XML source file that should be decorated.
5. Transform to HTML and behold the result.

More details can be found here: http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/UsingCSS.html.